# Implement a unique function to output a list of data in correct format in C

Tags: c

I'm now trying to do some tests for my simple c algorithms. And I find out it's quite often that I need to display a list of data. It'd be great if there is a function as below:

```
extern static void display_list(void *data, int size, char *fmtstr);

int main(void)
{
    int l0[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    double l1[] = {1.1, 2, 3, 4, 5.1};
    display_list(l0, 5, "%d");
    display_list(l1, 5, "%lg");
}
```

The anticipatory output would be:

> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
>     { 1.1, 2, 3, 4, 5.1 }

It's just like a reversed parsing phrase from C format string into relative data type.

My first try is as below:

```
void display_list(void *data, int size, char *fmtstr)
{ int i;

    printf("{ ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (memcmp(fmtstr, "%d", sizeof(char)) == 0)
            printf(fmtstr, ((int *)data)[i]);
        else if (memcmp(fmtstr, "%lg", sizeof(char)) == 0)
            printf(fmtstr, ((double *)data)[i]);
        else if (memcmp(fmtstr, "%lf", sizeof(char)) == 0)
            printf(fmtstr, ((double *)data)[i]);
        else if (memcmp(fmtstr, "%c", sizeof(char)) == 0)
            printf(fmtstr, ((char *)data)[i]);

        if (i < size - 1) printf(", ");
    }
    printf(" }\n");
}
```

The output of int array is correct but I don't know why the output of double array messed up:

> l1: { 6.95321e-310, 6.95321e-310, 6.95321e-310, 6.95321e-310, 6.95321e-310 }

Seems that I've make some mistake about `memcmp`. Could anyone tell me what the problem is.
And it'd be better if someone offer me a solution to implement such function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason is probably because you use `memcmp` instead of `strcmp` for the format string. And you compare only *one character*. The expression `sizeof(char)` returns the size of a single `char`, and it's specified to always return `1` as well.

The above means that you only compare the *first* character, the `'%'`, and the first check will always be true. In other words, you will cast the `double` to an `int` and print that as a `double`, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Use `strcmp` to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is logically incorrect: `(memcmp(fmtstr, "%d", sizeof(char))`

You are comparing two strings but you are giving number of bytes to compare as `1` to `memcmp`.

You can use it this way: `(memcmp(fmtstr, "%d", strlen("%d"))`

So how is it causing the problem in your case??

Every time, you call the function with some `fmtstr` (e.g. `%lg`) then `memcmp` starts comparing strings byte by byte but continues only for one character, therfeore `%` which is the first character matches in first case itself.

Now the call to printf is made as `printf("%lg", ((int*) data)[i]);`

Since `double` is `8` bytes and `int` is `4` bytes `printf` accesses wrong data for printing.

Answer (score 0):

There are already answers that have pointed out how you can fix your problem. I am going to suggest something that will avoid repeated use of `memcmp` or `strcmp`.

```
void display_list(void *data, int size, char *fmtstr)
{
   int i;

   int* intData = NULL;
   double* doubleData = NULL;
   char* charData = NULL;

   printf("{ ");
   if (strcmp(fmtstr, "%d") == 0)
   {
      intData = (int*)data;
      for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
          printf(fmtstr, intData[i]);
      }
   }
   else if (strcmp(fmtstr, "%lg") == 0 ||
            strcmp(fmtstr, "%lf") == 0)
   {
      doubleData = (double*)data;
      for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
          printf(fmtstr, doubleData[i]);
      }
   }
   else if (strcmp(fmtstr, "%c") == 0)
   {
      charData = (char*)data;
      for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
          printf(fmtstr, charData[i]);
      }
   }

   printf(" }\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (memcmp(fmtstr, "%d", sizeof(char)) == 0)
        printf(fmtstr, ((int *)data)[i]);
```

This is just comparing 1 character that is just `%` because you gave `sizeof(char)` so your first if will always be satisfied, it won't go to the `if else` statement.

```
else if (memcmp(fmtstr, "%lg", sizeof(char)) == 0)  //Control will never go to this      
    printf(fmtstr, ((double *)data)[i]);            //statement.
```

So instead of sizeof(char) you can use directly

```
if (memcmp(fmtstr, "%d", 3) == 0)
        printf(fmtstr, ((int *)data)[i]);
    else if (memcmp(fmtstr, "%lg", 4) == 0)
        printf(fmtstr, ((double *)data)[i]);
    else if (memcmp(fmtstr, "%lf", 4) == 0)
        printf(fmtstr, ((double *)data)[i]);
    else if (memcmp(fmtstr, "%c", 3) == 0)
        printf(fmtstr, ((char *)data)[i]);
```